# Selenium code to wait until CSS class is available and extract text in Python

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have looked at some questions on here that are somewhat related but none of them are concerned with finding a class and then extracting text that is part of that class.

My goal is to automate the process of entry into a website that finds emails, given name and domain names. So far I have the code to automate the entry of the name and domain, and then click on "search", but my issue is waiting for a result to load. I basically want my code wot wait until the CSS class "one" is present and then extract the text related to this class, e.g. for the following snippet:

```
<h3 class="one">Success</h3>
```

Extract the text "Success".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to *[explicitly wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the element to become visible*:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
h3 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))
print h3.text
```

Comment: I am getting this error:                                                                                                 File "/Users/sinaastani/AskNorbert/finder.py", line 18, in <module>
    h3 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium-2.45.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 75, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @ohbrobig then, it appears that this element is not getting visible.

Comment: @ohbrobig any iframes on the page? Is the element really represented as `<h3 class="one">Success</h3>`? Thanks.

Comment: there are iframes on the page, but the element is really represented that way

Comment: @ohbrobig iframes are your current problem. You need to switch to an iframe and then wait for an element: `driver.switch_to.frame('frame_id_or_name')`.

Comment: @ohbrobig there are all sorts of techniques to locate it, can you share the HTML representation of the frame?

Comment: <iframe name="stripeXDM_default278558_provider" id="stripeXDM_default278558_provider" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/channel.html?stripe_xdm_e=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.voilanorbert.com&amp;stripe_xdm_c=default278558&amp;stripe_xdm_p=1#__stripe_transport__" frameborder="0" style="position: absolute; top: -2000px; left: 0px;"></iframe>

Comment: @ohbrobig thanks, how about `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'stripeXDM_')]"))`?

Comment: I don't think iframes are a problem here actually...but I was able to make it work doing a variation of your code which finds a different (yet pretty much identical) element.

Comment: Heh, I think I found the problem. The opacity of the element "h3.one" is 0. So when converting to text I am getting an empty string.